# Did i damage my car by driving with the hand brake on

Tags: handbrake

I was in a rush and I reversed with my handbrake up then proceeded to drive about 100 meters in 2nd gear, when I came to  a stop i noticed that my handbrake was still up.

I might be overthinking since im still a beginner driver but something just doesn't feel right with the car.

Can you please give some insight

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!